# Gram-Schmidt on complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

I am really frustrated because i just cant find my error.

Let 
$\quad v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\i \end{pmatrix} , v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\-i\\1 \end{pmatrix} , v_3 = \begin{pmatrix}i \\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$

**First step**

$ s_1 = \frac{v_1}{|v_1|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\i \end{pmatrix}$

**Second step**

$w_2 = v_2 -<v_2,s_1>\cdot s_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\-i\\1 \end{pmatrix} - <\begin{pmatrix}0 \\-i\\1 \end{pmatrix},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\i \end{pmatrix}>\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\i \end{pmatrix} $

$w_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\-i\\1 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{i}{2}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\\i \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}-i \\-2i\\3 \end{pmatrix}$

$s_2 = \frac{w_2}{|w_2|} \quad \text{with} \quad |w_2| = \sqrt{\frac{7}{2}} \Longrightarrow s_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{14}} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}-i \\-2i\\3 \end{pmatrix}$

According to Wolfram Alpha this is wrong already and i cant find my mistake. I hope you can help me here.

Comment: Maybe you should use this approach https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#The_Gram.E2.80.93Schmidt_process organize so that you first get the orthogonal vectors. You can make them of unit length when you are done.

Comment: Finally found my mistake. Misused the definition of sesquilinear form

Comment: Meaning you forgot taking a conjugate?  Anyway, I'm a bit rusty, but for sure a sesquilinear form is not an inner product.

Comment: Yup the conjugate killed me